# Log hits on advertiser images

Tags: plugin-recommendation

We have a few "sponsor" images on our site which link to our.. well, sponsors!

[image: Sponsors]

**Source**

```
<a href="http://www.amazon-below-water.com/" target="_blank" alt="Amazon Below Water"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/BelowWater.png" alt="" /></a>
<a href="http://www.pieraquatics.com/" target="_blank" alt="Pier Aquatics"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/PierAquatics.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" alt="Ichthyological Exploration of Freshwaters"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/IEF.png" alt="" /></a>
<a href="http://www.amazonasmagazine.com/" target="_blank" alt="Amazonas Magazine"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/sponsor1.png" alt="" /></a>
```

What I'd like, ideally, is a plugin which can track the hits on these images; i.e. to show me that `170 clicks have been made on all of our sponsors; 34 on the Amazonas`. Obviously it doesn't need to be this specific, and I guess the plugin would have to set these images up in the first place. That's all fine.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you checked out [AdRotate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adrotate/)?

Comment: Haven't looked at anything my friend! Will investigate now, thanks.

Comment: Post that as an answer ericissocial - works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AdRotate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adrotate/) allows you to track clicks on as many ads as you want to set up.

It also allows advertisers to have a special log in so that they may check their own statistics or even update their own ads if you want to give them that power.

It's a pretty robust system with decent support and some cool features planned on the horizon (from what the developer told me when I asked him a question about better integration with theme development).

Note: If AdRotate is too robust for your needs, this could be implemented on your own through some Ajax calls when a user clicks on an div with a specific class. These clicks could be saved in a table or via options. But, honestly, AdRotate does it so well that I haven't seen the need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It has actually saved me some extra code in my `functions.php` too and is pretty neat, so thanks very much for that recommendation.